# Se puede conectar un servidor windows con otro servidor windows mediante java?

Tags: java

Que tal mi problema es el sig. Tengo que realizar un proceso java que va estar alojado en un servidor Windows(Servidor 1), este servidor va a ejecutar el .jar el cual se tiene que conectar a otro Servidor windows(Servidor 2) para buscar un archivo, leerlo, extraer un fragmento de texto (esto en el servidor 2), de ahi crear un archivo en el servidor 1 con el fragmento que se extrajo del archivo en el servidor 2.

Es posible conectar Al servidor 1 con el Servidor 2 utilizando java?. Hice algo parecido pero de windows a Linux abriendo una Conexion SSH desde java pero no le hayo como a este.

Alguien tendra un ejemplo de como se realizaria la conexion entre ambos servidores.Es lo que me esta causando problemas. Gracias otra ves

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, si si se puede.

Comment: Gracias, de casualidad contaras con algún ejemplo de como realizar la conexión entre ambos servidores?

Comment: Necesitas investigar sobre sistemas distribuidos y en especial java trabaja con una clase que se llama RMI (Remote Method Invocation

Answer (score 0):

no tengo muy claro TODO el proceso, pero en algo te podré orientar al menos para que re-dirijas tu búsqueda hacia el lugar mas cercano al exito...

(Busca usar sockets TCP  / Los UDP no te Ayudaran por "la pérdida" de datos) ;)

Primero necesitas un Servidor y un cliente, el servidor almacena los datos y los devuelve hacia el/los clientes(también funciona a la inversa) , por medio de una conexión por sockets (tendrás algo así como un "chat") podrás pasar cualquier tipo de dato que desees (solo que unos mas difíciles de manejar que otros)... cargas la ruta del archivo al socket y este transfiere los datos al otro lado del socket, realmente es un tema un poco largo como para dejar codigo pero en el siguiente link verás una implementación de lo que te hablo...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Y6hawPB-E

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible y las opciones son muy amplias.

Ejemplo 1: dado que en el servidor 2 se debe buscar y procesar un fichero  el servidor 2 podria tener otra aplicación en Java que realice este proceso.

En este caso la aplicación podria exponer un servicio (REST/SOAP) o una conexion TCP/IP con Sockets Java para que la aplicación del servidor 1 la llame pidiendole la información y dando esta la respuesta adecuada.

Ejemplo 2: La aplicación del servidor 1 podria acceder a una carpeta en red compartida con el servidor 2 como una ruta cualquiera de acceso a disco mapeada a una unidad. Esto le permitira buscar por si misma el fichero y procesarlo. NO es la opción mas recomendable pero es una opción

Ejemplo 3: El servidor 2 puede implementar algun protocolo de acceso como FTP /HTTP... mediante algun servidor integrado (por ejemplo IIS) y la aplicación del servidor 1 usar algunas de las multiples librerias de cliente Java que permitieran acceder al directorio del servidor 2 mediante estas aplicaciones y realizar la búsqueda y operación

Y asi podriamos seguir enumerando multiples ejemplos de arquitecturas posibles. La pregunta tiene una amplia variedad de respuestas que dependen de como se quiera implementar la solución.